# How do i differentiate between two endpoints, each with one PathVariable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, endpoint

I'm working on a Spring Boot application. I have the following REST endpoint(s):

```
 @GetMapping(value = { "/person/{name}", "/person/{age}" })
 public PersonData getPersonData(@PathVariable(required = false) String name,
                                 @PathVariable(required = false) Integer age) {

}
```

This endpoint can be called with either a name variable or an age variable, however it looks like it can't differentiate between them. If I was to call '.../person/20', it would not call "/person/{age}", but it always calls "/person/{name}".

I know I could make something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/person/name/{name}", "/person/age/{age}" })
```

However are there any other way to solve it without adding anything to the path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A path variable is something like a primary key usually.

Like:

```
/person/{id}
```

What you try is to search for data and this should be done with query parameters.

Example:

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/person/{name}", "/person/{age}" })
public PersonData getPersonData(@RequestParam String name,
                                @RequestParam Integer age) {

}
```

Then you can call it

```
/person?age=40
/person?name=Peter
```

Comment: Okay, let's say they where Id's then what?

Comment: You cannot have two different ids for a rest endpoint just one

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli isn't {name} and {age} considered to be path variables?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli from my knowledge it should be `value = { "/person" }` and not `value = { "/person/{name}", "/person/{age}" }` . Have I missed something here?

Comment: `{ "/person/{name}", "/person/{age}" }` should just be `"/person"`. No need to use path variables

Answer (score 2):

`age` and `name` are logically *not* the same thing; the chosen best answer correctly suggests to keep them as distinguished parameters.

However you can check if the value is numeric and treat it like an `age`,

```
@GetMapping("/person/{value}")
public String getPerson(@PathVariable String value) {
    if (value.matches("[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]"))
        return "Age";
    else
        return "Name";
}
```

but this is ambiguous and error prone (e.g. how'll you distinguish when adding other numerical params like `shoeSize` or `numberOfPartners`?).

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would make 2 different endpoints to be more clear, each one requiring it's own query parameter to be served.

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/person")
 public PersonData getPersonDataByName(@RequestParam(required = true) String name) {
 ....
}


 @GetMapping(value = "/person")
     public PersonData getPersonDataByAge(@RequestParam(required = true) Integer age) {
 ....   
    }
```

`required = true` can be omitted from the annotation as this is the default value, I used it just to point that each endpoint will be fulfilled only for that specific query parameter